# Variation of Ricci tensor - perturbative gravitational waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, variational-calculus

I'm trying to calculate $\delta R_{\mu\nu}$ and prove that it is zero in empty space. I have calculated the variation of the Riemann tensor and substituted in the Christoffel symbols and arrived at this equation.

From $\delta R_{\mu\nu}=\delta R^\alpha_{\mu \alpha \nu}$ I have:

$$
\delta R_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha \delta}\left(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\delta g_{\delta\alpha}+\nabla_\mu\nabla_\alpha\delta g_{\delta\nu}-\nabla_\mu\nabla_\delta\delta g_{\nu\alpha}-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu\delta g_{\delta\alpha}-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\alpha\delta g_{\delta\mu}+\nabla_\nu\nabla_\delta \delta g_{\mu\alpha}\right).
$$

The identities I can think of are $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ and $\nabla_\rho g_{\mu\nu}$ = 0 since this is a vacuum solution of the Einstein equations. The second derivative of the metric cannot be set to zero so this must be a manipulation of the indices that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is zero. The first and the fourth term cancel out(if there is no torsion you can change the covariant derivatives). Then use the metric outside the parenthesis to make $\nabla_{α}$ and $\nabla_{δ}$, $\nabla^{α}$ and $\nabla^{δ}$ respectively and if you make the change $\alpha \rightarrow \delta$ and  $\delta \rightarrow \alpha $ in the remaining terms you're there.

Comment: Thanks! I had not realised how close I actually was!

Comment: "if there is no torsion you can change the covariant derivatives" --> Did you mean curvature instead of torsion?

Comment: I meant that $\Gamma^{a}_{bc} = \Gamma^{a}_{cb}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for $\delta R_{\mu \nu}$ is incorrect, and it is incorrect that $\delta R_{\mu \nu}$ vanishes on a flat background. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/364476)

Comment: I’ve edited my response.